# Update value of input type time (rerender) and focus on element again with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the spec for my app it says (developerified translation): When tabbing to a time element, it should update with the current time before you can change it.

So I have:

```
<input type="time" ref="myTimeEl" onFocus={this.handleTimeFocus.bind(null, 'myTimeEl')} name="myTimeEl" value={this.model.myTimeEl} id="myTimeEl" onChange={this.changes} />
```

Also relevant

```
changes(evt) {
    let ch = {};
    ch[evt.target.name] = evt.target.value;
    this.model.set(ch);
},

handleTimeFocus(elName, event)
{
    if (this.model[elName].length === 0) {
      let set = {};
      set[elName] = moment().format('HH:mm');
      this.model.set(set);
    }
},
```

The component will update when the model changes. This works well, except that the input loses focus when tabbing to it (because it gets rerendered).

Please note, if I would use an input type="text" this works out of the box. However I MUST use type="time".

So far I have tried a number of tricks trying to focus back on the element after the re-render but nothing seems to work.

I'm on react 0.14.6

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you would need to:

1. Add a `focusedElement` parameter to the components state
2. In `getInitialState()`: set this parameter to `null`
3. In `handleTimeFocus()`: set `focusElement` to 'timeElem` or similar
4. Add a `componentDidUpdate()` lifecycle method, where you check if state has `focusedElement` set, and if so, focus the element - by applying a standard javascript `focus()` command.

That way, whenever your component updates (this is not needed in initial render), react checks if the element needs focus (by checking state), and if so, gives the element focus.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this already and decided it did not work. The problem was using focus(), which does not work in Chrome. select() works fine. I'm still a little bit put off by changing state twice when an element is focused but I guess I will have to live with it if there are no other solutions.

Comment: I don't think you need to update state twice (with two rerenders). You could do 1 setState() which updates both field input value + focusedElement parameter in one go.

Comment: Sorry my bad I should have explained it further. Changing the model will update component state causing a rerender, but I don't have access to the model via this.state. If I had, it could have been done as you say in one go.

Comment: I see. Well, I shouldn't worry too much about the "double render". React takes care of this (only updating DOM with what really changed).

Answer (score 0):

A solution for savages, [but I would rather not](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate)

```
handleTimeFocus(elName, event)
{
    if (this.model[elName].length === 0) {
      let set = {};
      set[elName] = moment().format('HH:mm');
      this.model.set(set);

      this.forceUpdate(function(){
        event.target.select();
      });
    }
},
```

Comment: Don't think this will work: assuming `this.model.set()` will trigger state or prop change, the `forceUpdate()` is never executed, or at best overruled. And maybe I am mistaken, but passing the select() function to a state update would probably not work as intended anyway.

Comment: This works, requires least amount of code, but it is advised against by the react documentation I linked to.

Answer (score 0):

try using **autoFocus** attrribute.

follow the first 3 steps mention by [wintvelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5358807/wintvelt).

then in render function check if the element was focused, based on that set the autoFocus attribute to true or false.

example:

```
render(){
  var isTimeFocused = this.state.focusedElement === 'timeElem' ? true : false;
  return(
<input type="time" ref="myTimeEl" onFocus={this.handleTimeFocus.bind(null, 'myTimeEl')} name="myTimeEl" value={this.model.myTimeEl} id="myTimeEl" onChange={this.changes}  autoFocus={isTimeFocused} />
  );
}
```